# Horizontal array constant definition issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I can't understand where I fail (except following MS-original help :-D) in attempt to enter horizontal array constant (C+S+E seq) per MS guidance accessible either from Excel 2007 or 2010 help, or at this link :
https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-3be0c791-3f89-4644-a062-8e6e9ecee523#__migbm_0

It's impossible. Trying some stupid ={1,2,3} seq is forced to 1,23 by sw, both 2007 and 2010 versions (got no 2013). Only vertical ={1;2;3} constant works.

No-one in the world per google (doing its best I hope so :) addressed this fundamtental feature failure (inc. MS Technet) so far, seems so.

Is there some explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Horizontal array constant definition issue

It's caused by your "Regional Settings". You have `,` specified as a decimal separator instead of the usual `.`

---

#### Excel 2007 temporay solution

> By default, Microsoft Excel uses the system separators that are defined in the regional settings in Control Panel. If you sometimes need to display numbers with different separators for thousands or decimals, you can temporarily replace the system separators with custom separators.
>
> 1. Click the Microsoft Office Button [image], and then click Excel Options.
> 2. On the Advanced tab, under Editing options, clear the Use system separators check box.
> 3. Type new separators in the Decimal separator and Thousands separator boxes.
>
> Tip: When you want to use the system separators again, select the Use
>   system separators check box.
>
> Note: For a permanent solution, you must change the regional settings in
>   Control Panel.

Source [Change the character used to separate thousands or decimals](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

---

#### Windows 7 permanent solution

You can change the system settings using "Control Panel" > "Region and Language" > "Formats" > "Additional settings" > "Decimal symbol"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Surely Excel uses an alternate delimiter if the regional settings use the comma as a decimal divider. It seems like it should just be a matter of identifying or defining that alternate delimiter instead of having to change your regional settings.

Comment: @Excellll From my answer "By default, Microsoft Excel uses the system separators that are defined in the regional settings in Control Panel. If you sometimes need to display numbers with different separators for thousands or decimals, you can temporarily replace the system separators with custom separators."

Comment: Thanks David for your reply, you saved my day or even more! I would not get to this by any means.. Great web full of experts! Bye.